# When comparing MGFs why is $X+2Y \ne X+Y+Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions, chi-squared

As the title states. I have $X \sim ChiSquare(2)$ and $Y \sim ChiSquare(2)$, i.e. they are both distributed as chi-squares with 2 degrees of freedom and are independent.

Define a new random variable $U = X+2Y$. After some calculation I have found that $X+2Y \ne X + Y + Y$. What is the reasoning for this?

EDIT: For clarity, my thinking was that if $U=X+2Y$ we could write it as $U=X+Y+Y$, as $2Y=Y+Y$.

EDIT: I attempted to solve this by making use of the fact that the MGF of the sum of independent random variables, is the product of the indiviudal MGFs.

Here for $X+Y+Y$ I treated this as $M_X(t) * M_Y(t) *M_Y(t)$, but this supposedley leads to the incorrect answer.

Comment: what calculation?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write $X + Y + Y$, what exactly do you mean by $Y + Y$?  Does this represent the sum of two independent random variables, each of which follows a chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom, or does it represent the sum of a single chi-squared random variable with itself?  In the former case, the notation is incorrect and would not be acceptable:  it should read $Y_1 + Y_2$, where $Y_i \sim \operatorname{ChiSquare}(2)$ for $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$.

To illustrate, suppose $Y$ is such a chi-squared random variable.  Using a computer, I generated the realization $Y = 1.36952$.  Now, when I write $Y + Y$, what I mean is the realization $Y + Y = 2.73905$.  However, if what is intended is the sum of two independent and identically distributed chi-squared random variables, then you could have $$Y_1 + Y_2 = 1.36952 + 2.37966 = 3.74918.$$  The second realization, although coming from the same distribution, has a different value than the first.

Whenever something like $Y+Y$ is written, even for random variables, it should be clear that $Y+Y = 2Y$ identically.  This is why, if the intent was to represent two IID chi-squared random variables, rather than twice a single chi-squared random variable, such notation is incorrect, and the notation $Y_1 + Y_2$ or something similar to distinguish the two variables, must be used.

---

After seeing your edit, the error is that if $U = X + Y + Y$, you cannot write
$$M_U(t) = M_X(t)M_Y(t)M_Y(t).$$  This is incorrect because the two instances of $Y$ are **always equal**, hence **not independent**.  Then the theorem does not apply.  If $U = X + Y_1 + Y_2$ where each variable in the sum is independent, then you could write $M_U(t) = M_X(t) M_{Y_1}(t) M_{Y_2}(t)$.

Comment: It was supposed to mean a single Chi-Square(2) variable summed with itself. Thank you for the example but I don't understand how it relates to comparison of MGFs. Why doesn't $X+2Y$ have the same MGF as $X+Y+Y$?

Comment: @HungaryGoose If it means what you claim it means, then $X + Y + Y = X + 2Y$, and the MGFs must be the same.  Since you did not show your computation of the MGFs, I cannot tell you why you think they ought to be different.

Comment: I have made a second edit to the post. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: @HungaryGoose See my response in my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks heropup, I missed the independence condition.